# Equivalent definition of a coset of some subspace of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am given that $V$ is a vector space over the field $F$, and $X$ is a nonempty subset of $V$ with the following property. $Y=\{x_1-x_2|x_i\in X\}$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication by elements of $F$. I want to show that this is equivalent to $X$ being a coset of some subspace of $V$.

If I show that $v_1+X=v_2+X \iff v_1-v_2\in X$, will this be sufficient? Also would the set $Y$ as defined above be the quotient space $V/X$? ie   ($V$ modulo $X$)

Edit, actually I am thinking that $X$ as defined above is not a coset by the counterexample $V=\mathbb{R}$ and $X=\mathbb{R^+}\cup \{0\}$. Can anyone confirm this?